# How to observe WorkManager during Configuration Change?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am investigating the use of `androidx.work.WorkManager` for background work within my current Android application.

The versions I am employing are :-

```
compileSdkVersion = 27
targetSdkVersion = 27
minSdkVersion = 21
buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"

archLifecycleVersion = "1.1.1"
archWorkerRuntimeVersion = "1.0.0-alpha11"
```

My application consists of An activity with a Fragment, the Fragment has an associated `android.arch.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel` and the view model has a repository.

I control the WorkManager from within my repository class.

I set the fragment as the LifecycleOwner for the workManager Observer.

When I allow the workManager to complete its work without changing the orientation of my testing device it works as designed.

However when I start the workManager and then during its background processing I change the device orientation my observer is removed as the Fragment has been destroyed. The work manager still completes with success as I can see this in my application logs...

```
WorkerWrapper: Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=33058369-010d-4e07-ae94-fb04bcf4d805, tags={ com.sync.SyncWorker, SYNC-IN-PROGRESS-TAG } ]
```

I switched to using observeForever, however this approach gave worse results as my observer only received `ENQUEUED` and `RUNNING`, it never "saw" the `SUCCEEDED` state, even though I still saw the above `WorkerWrapper` log entry.

How can I observe WorkManager work before during and after a device configuration change?

My Code resembles this:-

```
private WorkManager mWorkManager;

/**
 * SINGLETON
 */
private MyRepository() {
    mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
}


private static final String WORK_IN_PROGRESS_TAG = "SYNC-IN-PROGRESS-TAG";
private static final String UNIQUE_WORK_NAME = "SYNC-UNIQUE_WORK_NAME";
private final Observer<WorkInfo> workerObserver = constructWorkStatusObserver();

private Observer<WorkInfo> constructWorkStatusObserver() {
    return workInfo -> {

        if (workInfo == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (workInfo.getState().equals(WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED)) {
            //DO SOMETHING 
        } else if (workInfo.getState().equals(WorkInfo.State.FAILED)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "SyncWorker FAILED:");
        }
    };
}


private Action manageSuccess(final LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner) {
    return () -> {
        final LiveData<WorkInfo> workStatus = constructWorkRequest();
        workStatus.observe(lifecycleOwner, workerObserver);
    };
}

private LiveData<WorkInfo> constructWorkRequest() {
    final OneTimeWorkRequest refreshDatabaseWork = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SyncWorker.class).addTag(WORK_IN_PROGRESS_TAG).build();

    mWorkManager.beginUniqueWork(UNIQUE_WORK_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, refreshDatabaseWork).enqueue();
    return mWorkManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(refreshDatabaseWork.getId());
}
```

Comment: can you post code about how you observe result ?

Comment: @JeelVankhede yes, just added it, what mistake have I made?

Comment: You can try observing livedata by your unique work tag with this method `getWorkInfosByTagLiveData` in your `constructWorkRequest`. May be your observer getting null due to id change.